Need help writing Calculated Column IF/OR statement
Current Columns:
Issue date, Closed date, Days to completion.
Days to completion = Calculated Column set as number for data type returned.
Goal= Days to completion column will either be blank (because Closed date has not been entered yet) or it will show the days to completion (Closed date - Issue date)
I have reviewed other suggestions and attempted to use this: =IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date 1]),ISBLANK([Date 2])),"",DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"D"))
However it does not produce the results I am after.
Looking forward to trying your suggestions.
Thanks!

=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Date 2])),NOT(ISBLANK([Date 1]))),DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"d"), "")



